# Do curved moving objects tend to move away along the normal direction of the curve?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

Do curved moving objects (Such as a ball moving along a curve path) tend to move away along the normal direction of the curve? Because of the centripetal force, it is not really far away, but every moment there is this trend. Right?

I mean the tendency to move along the normal direction of the curve.

Comment: Not clear. What is a "curved moving object?" A ball or ellipsoid? Or do you mean a moving object which follows a curved path? Also, "move away" from what? From a straight line path?

Comment: @BillN Such as a ball moving along a curve path.

Comment: @BillN I mean the tendency to move along the normal direction of the curve.

Comment: Read Newton's first law of motion

Answer (score 1):

The only way to deviate from a straight line path is to have an instantaneous normal component of motion. The time-progressive sum of these deviations gives the curved path.

Deviations from straight line paths require an acceleration which means some component of force must be normal to the instantaneous velocity.

Comment: That is to say, the ball tends to move away from the path in the normal direction, right?

Answer (score 0):

No, it tends to move along the tangential direction to the curve. You can see this by stopping the centripetal force that makes he move in a circular path. For instance, if the centripetal force is provided by a rope and you cut the rope, the object will start moving straight in a direction perpendicular to that of the rope at the moment of the cut

Comment: I understand your answer and don't necessarily disagree because the question is extremely ambiguous. I simply interpreted OPs question differently. "Tend" is an ambiguos word.

Comment: yes, it also depends on what is your system of reference. If you are rotating with the ball it will look like your tendency is to move outwards due to the centrifugal pseudo-force, but this is an illusion because the path after  you cut the rope  will now look like a spiral (if your system of coordinates keeps rotating)

Comment: @BillN It's getting away from the center of the circle, if you cut the rope.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny The object moving along the curve path has centrifugal force, so it tends to leave the center of the circle.

Comment: it all depends in what system of reference you are. If you are rotating with the object, then yes, if you are in an inertial frame of reference, then no

Comment: @Wolphramjonny After cutting the rope, in fact, the ball is farther and farther away from the center of the circle. In what reference system is this measurement made?

Comment: in the inertial system it will be a straight line, tangential to the circle, not radial, and in the rotating system it will be a spiral